# Importar dados de um txt para planilha EXCEL através de VBA

Tags: vba, txt

Gostaria de ajuda para importar esse arquivo para uma planilha do excel através de VBA

Esses dados abaixo são os que estão no arquivo txt para importação, para me ajudar, basta salva-los no bloco de notas

```
01|20190521|20190522|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
02|AALR3|CENTRO DE IMAGE|23|139855|2090832.25|0.10|0.23|0.29|0.25|0.27|0.35
02|ABCB4|BANCO ABC BRASI|169|318440|5754210.80|0.17|0.27|0.35|0.29|0.65|2.00
02|ABEV3|AMBEV S/A|111|6343826|107274097.66|0.04|0.11|0.20|0.09|0.21|1.05
02|ADHM3|HUB COSMETICOS S.A.|2|6|8.16|3.00|3.00|3.00|5.00|5.00|5.00
02|AGRO3|BRASILAGRO CIA|3|207369|3241177.47|0.06|0.15|0.15|0.31|0.33|1.30
02|ALPA4|ALPARGATAS S/A|35|214257|3578091.90|0.08|0.15|0.25|0.15|0.30|0.90
02|ALSC3|ALIANSCE SHOPPI|28|452498|8466237.58|0.05|0.09|0.10|0.13|0.14|0.80
02|ALUP11|ALUPAR INVESTIM|11|86479|1969991.62|0.05|0.12|0.20|0.15|0.22|0.60
02|ALUP3|ALUPAR INVESTIM|1|1|7.87|2.00|2.00|2.00|5.00|5.00|5.00
02|AMAR3|MARISA LOJAS S.|8|42302|291037.76|0.13|0.21|0.48|0.30|0.39|1.60
02|ANIM3|ANIMA HOLDING S|6|11522|225715.98|0.12|0.32|1.11|0.25|0.50|3.00
02|APER3|BR INSURANCE CO|1|5|115.80|0.41|0.41|0.41|1.10|1.10|1.10
02|ARMT34|ARCELOR MITTAL|1|664|22808.40|6.40|6.40|6.40|6.45|6.45|6.45
02|ARZZ3|AREZZO INDUSTRI|12|118700|5711844.00|0.25|0.92|1.10|0.25|1.11|1.60
02|AZUL4|AZUL S.A|21|349446|12335443.80|0.15|0.28|0.50|0.30|0.31|2.00
```

desde já agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Henrique boa tarde!

Espero que ajude, execute a sub **importar_arquivo()**

```
Sub importar_arquivo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    importaArquivo
End Sub

Private Function importaArquivo()
    Dim arquivo As String
    arquivo = abrirArquivo
    If arquivo <> Empty Then
        Debug.Print "ok"
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'nova planilha
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & arquivo & "", Destination:=Range("A1"))
            .Name = "teste"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End If
    arquivo = ""
End Function

Function abrirArquivo() As String
    Dim arquivo As String
    On Error GoTo sair:
    arquivo = ""
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
          'Selecção de apenas um aquivo
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
          'Filtro de extenção
          .Filters.Add "All files", "*.txt; *.csv"
          'Mostra a caixa de dialogo
          .Show
          'Armazena o caminho do arquivo
          arquivo = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    abrirArquivo = arquivo
sair:
    arquivo = ""
End Function
```

Comment: excelente, ajudou muito, muito obrigado